# ng-model is not updated, i used javascript library for change language in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-model cant't update untill i press space or back space..

I think this problem arrived because of i use third party library for changing language.

my laguage changing library is http://techhive.co.in/angular_language.js

```js
angular.module("MyApp",[])
 .controller("MyCtrl",function($scope,$http,$timeout){ 
   changeLanguage('pramukhindic:gujarati');
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='MyApp'>
<head>
<title>ng-model can't update</title>
<meta charset="UTF8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://techhive.co.in/angular_language.js"> </script>

</head>
<body >
<div >
    <div ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
      <h3>ng-model not update untill we press space or backspace.</h3>
 <form name="main_member_form">
 <input id="tags" ng-model="test"/>
 <label ng-bind="test"></label>
 </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Advance Thanks For Help.

Comment: Why do you use jQuery instead of angular to get an element?

Comment: @MateuszSip OP might have loaded angular before jQuery..so that does compile DOM in `jQLite` version. and in that case if you want `jQuery` methods then you have to compile that DOM with jQuery again.. but usually best practice is load jQuery before angular..so that DOM would get compiled with jQuery

Comment: see i remove all extra libraries...

Comment: @PankajParkar
OP already modified his code, but there was a jQuery specific code inside angular specific code.

About OPs problem: when you want to update angular's model by an external DOM modification, you have to call an $apply  function on a scope object. You should read about angular's digest cycle to get known with angular basics.

Comment: changeLanguage() function only use for switch lenguage and this call only one time..  and problem is that  there not update ng-model  $scope variable.. if i press space button from key board they that update only.

Comment: @MateuszSip I don't think so you do have understood anything from my last comment :D LOL.. and about what you are saying, I already did added answer 40 mins ago(while added this comment)..do care before adding comment in ruthless manner.. I do know angular very, I know it very well, [here is proof](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/topusers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are updating `angular` context from 3rd party library, for those changes angular digest system doesn't aware of those changes. So even if outside world has change something that wouldn't updated angular scope binding on view, unless you run digest cycle.

Here in this case you are modifying context from event which is outside of angular context. For getting binding updated you need to run kick off digest cycle manually to see the changes on page using `scope.$apply()`/`$timeout`

```
$elem.on('focus', function () {
    //do add $timeout dependency over directive DI array.
    $timeout(function(){
       changeLanguage('pramukhindic:gujarati');
    })
});
```

**Update**

> OP has changed whole code to have method in controller itself.

I'd love to suggest you to stick with directive approach to it, so that you could have you can handle over each input field individually by having single directive. 3rd party plugin is internally updating DOM value property of input field, rather than updating `ng-model` value. In this case what you need to do is, you need to set `keyup` handle over input to listen to `onkeyup` event. And the do apply digest cycle using `$apply`, thereafter set the value present inside a DOM to `ng-model` would work

**Directive**

```
.directive('myLang', function($parse, $timeout) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign;
      console.log("Inside directive")
      element.on('keyup', function() {
        //upadate value of ngModel with value attached to DOM value attribute
        scope.$apply(function() {
          console.log(element.val())
          ctrl.$setViewValue(element.val());
          ctrl.$render(); //to update $modelValue
        });
      })
    }
  }
})
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KCxwbOJJMnNQb44H8eCv?p=preview)

Comment: this change language is only switch the language..   BDW  where i apply digest cycle. sry i dont have idea.

Comment: check now i remove all extra parts.

Comment: @sagarchopada could you look at [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hg7RXLR0JHX5J1vBiho7?p=preview) and let me know what you want

Comment: there you see  two way binding not work...  when you press  space from key board then it will update...  or you press back-space from key board then that update  otherwise can not chane the value of ng-model="test"

Comment: @sagarchopada do look at updated answer..it will help you.. Thanks :-)

Comment: i already did the same solution myself  same like yours... thanks for help.

Comment: If you found the way before, then you should let me know.. So I would not put effort with this. Though, Glad to know that it helped. Thanks

Comment: okay i will remember this thing... thanks for your huge effort.... Thank you so much...

Comment: i used  .on('keyup',function(){
                        var cval =$elem.val();
                        var modelSetter = $parse(attrs['ngModel']).assign;
                        modelSetter(scope, cval);
                    }); 

which is good?

Comment: which one is good practice? as per your opinion. i really want to know because i am new in angularjs.

Comment: There will be tie between this, if you're thinking of best practices.. I personally would recommend you to go for model.assign..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108173/discussion-between-sagar-chopada-and-pankaj-parkar).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of $scope.$evalAsync()  to run the digest cycle. Put the logic inside this method and your model will be upated